# Laravel 5 error message attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a way to add some additional attributes to the Laravel error messages?

`withErrors` method seems to allow setting either a string message or a MessageBag (which most likely comes from validator) for the response so that errors can then be accessed in the templates (from the session).

Is there any way to somehow customise the messages? Being able to add/set some attributes (like color, priority, source, icon etc.) to the message and then retrieve them in template would allow me to "decide" how to present it.

I guess one way to do it is by using named message bags, but that's not very convenient. In fact this way I would only "group" my messages and then would have to walk through every possible group in my template anyway.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Validation error messages are just key-value pairs so "standard" properties cannot be applied easily.

It is possible to customize the error messages text. If you are using form request validation then use the function messages()

Sometimes I am adding custom variables to view, for example myError which I know to display differently.

Comment: It's clear with validation messages. But I sometimes set my own. And since the message itself is basically just a string maybe the messagebag can have some attributes? Matching the actual message string in the template won't work for me. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: MessageBag interface API is described at http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html . Maybe setFormat and getFormat help you out?

Comment: Yes, I've seen this page. The format would be applied to the whole messagebag. And I would like to keep the html in the templates. But basically this is one way to do it. Thanks